# Rotation matrices and reference frames

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, rotation, mathematics

Lets say I have 2 3x3 rotation matrices, we will call them A and B. I am told to find frame B relative to A. how would I go about doing this basic operation? would I do it similar to position (with taking B's coordinates and subtracting A's points from them) or is it different? (or am I just an idiot and doing position with reference frames wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector with co-ordinates $v_A$ relative to frame $A$, how do you find its co-ordinates relative to frame $B$ ?

First you multiply  $v_A$ by $\mathbb A$ to rotate it back to the original frame, then you multiply by $\mathbb B^{-1}$ to rotate to frame $B$. Now you just need to find one matrix that combines these two operations.

Comment: How would I find that matrix?